# gamecenter turnbased save match data out of turn

Tags: ios, game-center

Any chance I can save/update matchdata even when it is not my turn?

```
[currentMatch saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
  if (error)
  { }];
```

The above code can be used if it is still this user's turn, but what if it is not this user's turn? How do I send data between two players?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS 6.0, you cannot. :(

- You can save match data without advancing the turn (assuming you are
  the current player). see - `saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData:completionHandler:`
- You can end a game out of turn. see - `participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:withCompletionHandler:`
- However, you cannot update match data out of turn.

[GKTurnBasedMatch Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void) advanceTurn

{

    NSData *updatedMatchData = [this.gameData encodeMatchData];

    NSArray *sortedPlayerOrder = [this.gameData encodePlayerOrder];

    this.MyMatch.message = [this.gameData matchAppropriateMessage];

    [this.myMatch endTurnWithNextParticipants: sortedPlayerOrder turnTimeOut: GKTurnTimeoutDefault

                  matchData: updatedMatchData completionHandler ^(NSError *error) {

        if (error)

        {

            // Handle the error.

        }

      }];

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I do want to know how can I send message when it is not the user's (hence I am not going to mess with the turns). I have searched for a while now without answer so I guess I need to deal with it outside of GameCenter. But thank you nonetheless!